# Shared Element transition between two similar textView with gravity="centre_vertical" in two different fragment is not smooth

Tags: android, android-fragments, shared-element-transition

I have 2 text views in two fragments. They are as below

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="mytext"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:transitionName="@string/my_transition"/>
```

And my second TextView is as below

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="mytext"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:transitionName="@string/my_transition"/>
```

My transition as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<transitionSet>
    <changeBounds />
    <changeTransform />
</transitionSet>
```

When the transition starts from first fragment to the second, the Text dropped a little lower from origin position before the animation go. Vice versa, when it return from second fragment to first, it appear a little higher from it's original position before starting the animate transition down.

If I use `android:gravity="top"`, then everything is smooth. Or if the `android:layout_height` is the same for both, everything is smooth as well. Why is the `android:gravity` != `top` should affect the transition animation smoothness?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because of the `android:layout_height` for both textViews are different.

Options:

1. Try make them the same height.
2. If you insist to keep two different heights, try change the margin of first textView to

This:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_margin="4dp"
        android:text="mytext"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:transitionName="@string/my_transition"/>
```

Hope this helps.